# Timepicker slider not getting the set value

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timepicker

Hello I have used timepicker.js for creating a calendar with hour and minute slider selections. Everything is working absolutely fine, but when I save my data, let's say I have chosen 14-10-2012 12:33PM, when I call that value in the input field it shows it, but when I click the input to show the timepicker dialog, the time and sliders are always at zero.
I can code it myself to show the correct time but I believe there should be an option in the timepicker that does that.

```
 ![function Timepicker() {
        this.regional = \[\]; // Available regional settings, indexed by language code
        this.regional\[''\] = { // Default regional settings
            currentText: 'Now',
            closeText: 'Done',
            ampm: false,
            amNames: \['AM', 'A'\],
            pmNames: \['PM', 'P'\],
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            timeSuffix: '',
            timeOnlyTitle: 'Choose Time',
            timeText: 'Time',
            hourText: 'Hour',
            minuteText: 'Minute',
            secondText: 'Second',
            millisecText: 'Millisecond',
            timezoneText: 'Time Zone'
        };
        this._defaults = { // Global defaults for all the datetime picker instances
            showButtonPanel: true,
            timeOnly: false,
            showHour: true,
            showMinute: true,
            showSecond: false,
            showMillisec: false,
            showTimezone: false,
            showTime: true,
            stepHour: 1,
            stepMinute: 1,
            stepSecond: 1,
            stepMillisec: 1,
            hour: 0,
            minute: 0,
            second: 0,
            millisec: 0,
            timezone: '+0000',
            hourMin: 0,
            minuteMin: 0,
            secondMin: 0,
            millisecMin: 0,
            hourMax: 23,
            minuteMax: 59,
            secondMax: 59,
            millisecMax: 999,
            minDateTime: null,
            maxDateTime: null,
            onSelect: null,
            hourGrid: 0,
            minuteGrid: 0,
            secondGrid: 0,
            millisecGrid: 0,
            alwaysSetTime: true,
            separator: ' ',
            altFieldTimeOnly: true,
            showTimepicker: true,
            timezoneIso8609: false,
            timezoneList: null,
            addSliderAccess: false,
            sliderAccessArgs: null
        };][1]
```

Comment: What does `![` do? I might be missing something but I think your syntax is invalid.

Comment: No, it is working, this must be added by stackoverflow, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To use only times for a time range use $.timepicker.timeRange():

```
var startTimeTextBox = $('#range_example_3_start');
var endTimeTextBox = $('#range_example_3_end');

$.timepicker.timeRange(
    startTimeTextBox,
    endTimeTextBox,
    {
        minInterval: (1000*60*60), // 1hr
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        start: {}, // start picker options
        end: {} // end picker options
    }
);
```